# How to make \hspace affect all paragraph lines?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I'm working on my resume, which I wrote in latex a year or two ago, and now I'm updating it and I'm a lot more rusty than I was expecting.

I have a small paragraph that I want shifted over with:

```
\hspace{2mm}
```

but that only pushes the initial line and not the whole paragraph, which makes my resume look sloppy and unprofessional.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to modify margins in latex is a list environment

for example `article` class defines

```
\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

which indents on both sides

Sounds like you might want

```
\newenvironment{zzz}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin0pt \leftmargin2mm }%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

But normally such an indentation should be handled by the code that is handling the heading or other material above the indent rather than having an environment that just indents.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm going to do the environment suggestion in the meantime, but I plan to look into managing it in the header code in the future.

Comment: The package `changepage` already has an interface for this.